# Product page can't show up correct upsell products in Magento EE

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I am using magento EE now. With the full page cache turned on, when I open a product page for the first time after I flush my cache, I can get the correct corresponding upsell and related products. But if I go to another product's page and come back to the first product's page, the related and upsell products associated with the second product show up. I tried to use hole punched blcok to solve this problem, but it didn't work.Please help me !!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a system bug or something else?Because I added some custom  modules to the local codepool so I don't know whether my custom modules affect this functionality or not?